# sql statement or while loop drawing a blank

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

My code below should be populating a list of about 7 items, but nothing is showing up. Can anybody tell me where the error is, maybe in the SQL statement? thanks

```
<?php
$page_title = 'View Your Sites';
include ('includes/header.html');
include ('includes/functions.php');
include ('includes/config.inc.php');
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} elseif (isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">This page has been accessed in error.</p>';
    include ('includes/footer.html');
    exit();
}
if (isset($_SESSION['UserID'])){
require (MYSQL);
$w = "SELECT s.SiteTypeID, s.SiteType, u.url FROM sitetypes AS s LEFT JOIN sites AS u USING (SiteTypeID) WHERE UserID=$id";
$k = mysqli_query($dbc, $w)or trigger_error("Query: $w\n<br />mysqli Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
if (mysqli_num_rows($k) == 1){
while ($row33 = mysqli_fetch_array($k, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo '<table border="0"><th>Site Type</th><th>URL</th><tr><td>' . $row33['SiteType'] . '</td><td>' . $row33['url'] .'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
}

include ('includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Comment: to me `require (MYSQL);` looks suspecious

Comment: Your MySQL JOIN is incorrect. You need to exactly specify which columns to join. For example: LEFT JOIN sites AS u USING (u.SiteTypeID = s.SiteTypeID)

Comment: I have a suggestion run all you queries in phpmyadmin. Once you get the right ans then use the query in php